# Angular2-text-mask: editing the phone number makes the cursor jump to end

Tags: html, angular, masking

Editing the phone number makes the cursor to jump to the end.
Any suggestion will be a great help.
I followed the exact steps mentioned in:
http://www.coderbro.com/angular2/2017/04/21/format-phone-number-in-form-input-with-angular2.html

My code:

HTML and component class :

input type="text" class="input-underline-blue" id="phone" formcontrolname="phone" placeholder="(123) 345-2222" [textmask]="{mask: mask}" pattern="(?(\d{3}))?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4
})/" required=""/>

```
mask : any[] = ['(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, ')', ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/];
```

Comment: Please create a plunkr or something to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: Any error in console have you checked that. If yes means post that error.